# Powershell arguments list passing like -a <args list> -d <args list>

Tags: powershell, arguments, command-line-arguments, variadic-functions

I want to write a powershell ps1 script, which needs 2 argument sets,(-a -d) and each can have upto n attributes. How to implement that?

```
example : DoTheTask -a <task name 1> <task name 2> ...  -d <machine name 1> <machine name 2>...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
param(
    [string[]]$a,   
    [string[]]$d
)

write-host $a
write-host ----
write-host $d
```

Then you can call `DoTheTask -a task1,task2 -d machine1,machine2`

Comment: manojlds : DoTheTask -a task1,task2 -d machine1,machine2 This works fine. Is there a way where I can give the format without the , (comma) delimiting. example: DoTheTask -a task1 task2 -d machine1 machine2 machine3

Comment: I take the liberty in trying an answer: it's doable but rather tricky. Take a look at the `$MyInvocation` variable. Using its properties `Line`, `BoundParameters` and/or `UnboundArguments` should allow you to parse the parameters exactly the way you like.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you don't try modifying the syntax of PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you organize your task names and machines names in such a way that they can be put in to a single string with delimiters.

In other words, could your -a argument be a string a comma-separated task names and your -d argument be a string of comma-separated machine names? If so, then all you need to do is parse the string into its components at the start of your script.

Comment: Rather than passing as string, and then split etc, just pass in as array. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing these arguments to the script itself, you could leverage the `$args` internal variable, though key/value mapping will be a little trickier since PowerShell will interpret each statement as an argument. I suggest (like others) that you use another separator so that you can do the mappings easier.

Nonetheless, if you want to continue doing it this way, you can use a function like the below:

```
 Function Parse-Arguments {
    $_args = $script:args                                # set this to something other than $script:args if you want to use this inside of the script.
    $_ret  = @{}         
    foreach ($_arg in $_args) {
        if ($_arg.substring(0,1) -eq '-') {
            $_key = $_arg; [void]$foreach.moveNext()     # set the key (i.e. -a, -b) and moves to the next element in $args, or the tasks to do for that switch
            while ($_arg.substring(0,1) -ne '-') {       # goes through each task until it hits another switch
                $_val = $_arg
                switch($_key)    {
                     '-a'     {
                          write-host "doing stuff for $_key"
                          $ret.add($_key,$_val)          # puts the arg entered and tasks to do for that arg.
                     }

                     # put more conditionals here
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```